# Someone advise for checkout progrmatically

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying with checkout through externally programmmatically file. but no luck

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below steps to produce checkout stuff:

```
/*Get the Initial Store ID*/
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

/* Get one page checkouts singleton model */
$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');

/* Initialize the checkout this gets the current quote along with the associated  session and addresses */
$checkout->initCheckout();

/* Set the quote to the current store */
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());

/* As the session is created tell onepage to use the register method not guest */ 
$checkout->saveCheckoutMethod('register');

/* Set the shipping method you can use flatrate_flatrate aswell */
$checkout->saveShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping');

/* Save the payment method paypal_express, banktransfer, chekmo etc */
$order = $checkout->savePayment(array('method'=>'paypal_express'));

/** Try catch arround the save order method that does all the save and checks if the gateway needs to redirect.

try {
     $checkout->saveOrder();
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    /* If it fails then log the exception and sendpayment failed email. */
    Mage::logException($ex);
    Mage::helper('checkout')->sendPaymentFailedEmail($checkout->getQuote(), $ex->getMessage());

}

/* Get the redirect method and redirect from the controller */
$this->_redirectUrl($checkout->getQuote()->getPayment()->getCheckoutRedirectUrl())
```

Comment: where i can use this code? @nihar s